# Java JTable cannot set width of column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, width, jtableheader

I try to set width for the columns, but it didn't work at all, I have been searching for answers for hours, and here is my code, can anyone tell me what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    String [] columns = {"Day","StratTime","EndTime","Description"};
    mtbl = new DefaultTableModel();

    tbl = new JTable(mtbl);
    jsPane = new JScrollPane(tbl);

    tbl.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);


    for (int i = 0; i < Timedcolumns.length; i++) {
        mtbl.addColumn(columns[i]);
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(100);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of `addColumn()`, `JTable` may end up rebuilding all the columns. Here is a snippet from `JTable.tableChanged()` :

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    if (e == null || e.getFirstRow() == TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW) {
        ...

        if (getAutoCreateColumnsFromModel()) {
    // This will effect invalidation of the JTable and JTableHeader.
            createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
    return;
    }
        ...
```

`TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW` is fired as a result of `addColumn()` execution by `DefaultTableModel`. `addColumn` executes `fireTableStructureChanged`:

```
public void fireTableStructureChanged() {
    fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW));
}
```

You end up setting preferred size only on the last column that was added, as the rest of the columns were recreated by `createDefaultColumnsFromModel()`.

All in all, it is probably simpler to set preferred sizes after all the columns were created in a separate loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in addition to setting the PreferredWidth of a column, it is also helpful to set the maxWidth. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may also wish to set the minWidth.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Timedcolumns.length; i++) {
     mtbl.addColumn(columns[i]);
     tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(100);
     tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setMaxWidth(100);
 }
```

Comment: hah, I realize that need to separate the addColumn and setWidth in different loop, then it will work